# Find next incremental value not in existing list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two methods in an IntExtensions class to help generate the next available incremental value (which is not in a list of existing integers which need to be excluded).
I dont think I'm addressing the NextIncrementalValueNotInList method in the best way and am wondering if I can better use linq to return the next available int?

```
public static bool IsInList(this int value, List<int> ListOfIntegers) {
    if (ListOfIntegers.Contains(value))
        return true;

    return false;
}

public static int NextIncrementalValueNotInList(this int value, 
                                                List<int> ListOfIntegers) {

        int maxResult;
        maxResult = ListOfIntegers.Max() + 1;

        for (int i = value; i <= maxResult; i++)
        {
            if (!(i.IsInList(ListOfIntegers)))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return maxResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Using linq your method will look like:

```
return IEnumerable.Range(1, ListOfIntegers.Count + 1)
                  .Except(ListOfIntegers)
                  .First();
```

Comment: why use `Max()` at all?  It's causing two enumerations of `ListOfIntegers`.  Other than that I do like this solution

Comment: @AndrasZoltan, what is the alternative to using `Max()`?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it starting at 1.

You could also proceed like this:

```
IEnumerable.Range(1, ListOfIntegers.Count)
           .Where(i => !ListOfIntegers.Contains(i))
           .Union(new []{ ListOfIntegers.Count + 1 })
           .First();
```

Comment: Looking for the first gap + union (count + 1) = whichever comes first. It seems clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to calculate the `Max` value - just keep incrementing `i` until you find a value that doesn't exist in the list, e.g:

```
public static int NextIncrementalValueNotInList(this int value, 
  List<int> ListOfIntegers)
{
    int i = value;

    while(true)
    {
        if (!(i.IsInList(ListOfIntegers)))
        {
            return i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return maxResult;
}
```

.  Besides that, I'm not sure if there's much more you can do about this unless:

- `ListOfIntegers` is guaranteed to be, or needs to be, sorted, or
- `ListOfIntegers` doesn't actually need to be a `List<int>`

If the answer to the first is no, and to the second is yes, then you might instead use a `HashSet<int>`, which *might* provide a faster implementation by allowing you to simply use `HashSet<T>`'s own `bool Contains(T)` method:

```
public static int NextIncrementalValueNotInList(this int value, 
  HashSet<int> ListOfIntegers) 
{
    int i = value;
    while(true)
    {
        if (!(ListOfIntegers.Contains(i))
        {
            return value;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Note that this version shows how to do away with the `Max` check also.

Although be careful of premature optimisation - if your current implementation is fast enough, then I wouldn't worry.  You should properly benchmark any alternative solution with extreme cases as well as real-world cases to see if there's actually any difference.

Also what you don't want to do is use my suggestion above by turning your list into a `HashSet` for every call.  I'm suggesting changing entirely your use of `List` to `HashSet` - any piecemeal conversion per-call will negate any potential performance benefits due to the overhead of creating the `HashSet`.

Finally, if you're not actually expecting much fragmentation in your integer list, then it's possible that a `HashSet` might not be much different from the current Linq version, because it's possibly going to end up doing similar amounts of work anyway.